# Pandas - Add data to column based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

So I've esentially got this. A .csv file:

```
,year,team,tr_diff,ranking
0,2010,ADO Den Haag,3.9473684210526314,N/A
1,2011,ADO Den Haag,1.5120274914089347,N/A
2,2012,ADO Den Haag,-1.2320328542094456,N/A
3,2013,ADO Den Haag,-3.757828810020877,N/A
```

And this is my code:

```
rankings = [('ADO Den Haag', 12, 2010), ('ADO Den Haag', 16, 2011), .... ('ADO Den Haag', 12, 2013)]

df = pd.read_csv('preliminary.csv')
for tuple in rankings:      
    df.loc[(df['team'] == tuple[0]) & (df['year'] == tuple[2]), 'ranking'] = tuple[1]
```

The goal is to find a column that has the proper team-name and year, and add unto that row in the column 'Ranking' the ranking that can be found in the 2nd item of the tuple. How can I do this? This code doesn't raise any errors but it doesn't do what I want. The behaviour I'm hoping for is this.

```
,year,team,tr_diff,ranking
0,2010,ADO Den Haag,3.9473684210526314,12
1,2011,ADO Den Haag,1.5120274914089347,16
2,2012,ADO Den Haag,-1.2320328542094456,14
3,2013,ADO Den Haag,-3.757828810020877,15
4,2014,ADO Den Haag,2.5974025974025974,11
5,2015,ADO Den Haag,3.4702549575070822,8
6,2016,ADO Den Haag,-4.3626448534424,12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code should work I guess. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over the list of tuples. Use [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead. Assuming you have one entry in `rankings` for each entry in `df`You need:

```
ranking_df = pd.DataFrame(rankings, columns=['team', 'ranking', 'year'])
new_df = df.drop(['ranking'], axis=1).merge(ranking_df, on=['team', 'year'], how='left')
```

Input:

```
     year   team             tr_diff    ranking
0   2010    ADO Den Haag    3.947368    NaN
1   2011    ADO Den Haag    1.512027    NaN
2   2012    ADO Den Haag    -1.232033   NaN
3   2013    ADO Den Haag    -3.757829   NaN
```

Output:

```
    year    team             tr_diff    ranking
0   2010    ADO Den Haag    3.947368    12.0
1   2011    ADO Den Haag    1.512027    16.0
2   2012    ADO Den Haag    -1.232033   NaN
3   2013    ADO Den Haag    -3.757829   NaN
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work entirely actually. The df I get from declaring ranking_df is correct, but merging them doesn't work. The rankings don't go over into the new .csv. They merely become NaN.

Comment: @PEREZje are you saving it to csv correctly ?.. merge will return a new `df` , you have to use `to_csv` in this new df..

Comment: Yes I am saving it correctly, maybe the issue is that I have 192 datapoints in my original csv but only 142 in my list = rankings?

Comment: @PEREZje, if the list of ranking has less number of records than the df then consider the edited answer. All you need to do is ass `how='left'` in the `.merge()`. `new_df` will be the df with the rankings. It should easily be saved to the csv file. Note that you get `NaN` in new_df which says, rankings for those teams for that year is not provided in the list.

Comment: @HarvIpan great that works, it doesn't add NaN though.

Comment: @PEREZje, doesn't add NaN, where? Can you be specific?

Comment: @HarvIpan Sorry, it doesn't add NaN in the places where there's missing data, it merely leaves an empty string in the row.

Comment: @PEREZje, is that what you get in the csv file? If so, it is expected. If you `.read_csv()` read that csv file, those values would be shown NaN again. Note: CSV files will not have "NaN" as their values.

Comment: @HarvIpan ah that makes sense, I'm sorry. Very new to working with pandas as dataframes!

Comment: @PEREZje, no worries. Happy coding.